# Forcing Mobile style sheet of Google Maps v3

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to force the Mobile stylesheet for Google Maps v3 JavaScript in a jQueryMobile application.

When the screen stylesheet is used the zoom control is always at the top left and I have not been able to find a way of moving it.

When on mobile the controls are in the correct place (bottom right).

Setting a mobile user agent does not have any effect.

I am using the open source jquery-maps gmap libraries.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the position of the zoom-control by setting the [zoomControlOptions](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#ZoomControlOptions)-member the of mapOptions:

```
  zoomControlOptions:{position:google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM,
                      style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL}
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/YDxBh/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/YDxBh/)

This is the way by using the google-API, for a implementation using the plugin please refer to ressources for that plugin, I'm not sure which plugin you're talking about.